# Div id css code only working if place it underneath or next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display the div tag when the checkbox is checked. Everything is working, but when I move  tag down about a few lines, it stops working. If I put the  tab next to the input tag then it works fine.

css

```
#toggle-content-box{
display:none;
}
#mycheckbox:checked ~ #toggle-content-box{
 display:block;
height:100px;

}
```

If I place the div underneath the  line then it works perfectly.

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="file_id"  id="mycheckbox" value="">
 <div id="toggle-content-box">This div will display when checkbox above is checked</div>
```

But for some reason, I need to move this div down about 10 lines from the  line, then it stops working. The div is not showing when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Please show us the HTML structure for when it is not working. My guess is that the div has stopped being a sibling of the input. Is it inside another element?

Comment: It is too long I can't post in the comment https://www.mediafire.com/file/pw8ltokn22s3rvw/file.html/file

Comment: Dont try to post code in a comment, put just enough for us to see the problem into your actual question. There shouldn't be too much code for that if it's only around 20 lines extra that you have to show - at minimum show all the code between the input and that div.

Comment: Div should be descendent or sibling of the checkbox. So if you move it out from siblings then you can't access it by CSS. you can use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should declar the checkbox before the `div` not after it !

This is why when you put the `div` above the checkbox it is not working.

Comment: Im put the div after input tag down below maybe 20 lines of code.

Comment: when you put the `div` in the next 20 lines, is there any other tag above it?

Comment: yes, its too long I can't post in this comment. https://www.mediafire.com/file/pw8ltokn22s3rvw/file.html/file

Comment: so, this is the reason why it is not working :)